# Need to add range of author list on the table each row

Tags: tables, lists, parameters, author

I'm defining \author ten paramethers for a revision history table of document.

I am trying to add `\def\authos[1]` `\def\author[2]` and till 10 . Then I call this parameters in each row of my table `\author[1]` `\author[2]` till [10]. But when I am trying to create document I get following error message

`! Use of \author doesn't match its definition.
l.186 \author[1]...`

And when I am trying to run only with first author it passes.

Comment: Which documentclass do you use? Can you show us a short, **compilable** code resulting in your issue?

Comment: I use `\documentclass[a4paper,12pt,oneside]{book}`

Comment: I define my parametres like this 
```
\def\author[1]{Poghos}
\def\author[2]{Ann}
\def\author[3]{}
\def\author[4]{}
\def\author[5]{}
\def\author[6]{}
\def\author[7]{}
\def\author[8]{}
\def\author[9]{}
\def\author[10]{}
```
then I call them here

```
\textbf{Name Surname}    &    \textbf{Date} &     \textbf{Overview}    &   \textbf{Version} \\ 
\hline
\author[1] & \lastupdate & \overview & \version \\
\hline
\author[2] & \lastupdate & \overview & \version\\
\hline
```

Comment: Please follow this link https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/228/ive-just-been-asked-to-write-a-minimal-example-what-is-that to learn how to build a MWE. Add it to your question and help us to help you ...